# Merge and concat two arrays of objects - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have two array of objects and I want to merge them based on different properties and also concat if something doesnt exist in the list.

This is what I have:

```js
const data1 = [{
  name: 'A',
  id: 1
}, {
  name: 'B',
  id: 2
}]

const data2 = [{
  city: 'X',
  rowID: 1
}, {
  city: 'Y',
  rowID: 2
}, {
  city: 'Z',
  rowID: 3
}]

const result = _.map(data1, function(p) {
  return _.merge(
    p,
    _.find(data2, {
      rowID: p.id
    })
  )
})

console.log(result)

//Expected Result
/**[
  {
    "name": "A",
    "id": 1,
    "city": "X",
    "rowID": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "id": 2,
    "city": "Y",
    "rowID": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "",
    "id": "",
    "city": 'Z',
    "rowID": 3
  }
]*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could collect the merged object with a `Map` and get the values.

```js
const
    merge = data => {
        const
            pattern = {},
            map = new Map;

        data.forEach(([objects, key]) => {
            Object.keys(objects[0]).forEach(k => pattern[k] = '');
            objects.forEach(o => map.set(o[key], { ...map.get(o[key]), ...o }));
        });
        return Array.from(map.values(), o => ({ ...pattern, ...o }));
    },
    data1 = [{ name: 'A', id: 1 }, { name: 'B', id: 2 }],
    data2 = [{ city: 'X', rowID: 1 }, { city: 'Y', rowID: 2 }, { city: 'Z', rowID: 3 }],
    result = merge([[data1, 'id'], [data2, 'rwoID']]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I do not want to create a new object named empty as the keys are dynamic and will change per API. I am planning to use this as a reusable function where I pass in the two data, and their corresponding keys to match

Comment: Look at the last object of the expected results.

Comment: @OriDrori, if i should not take a default object, how should the result have ungiven properties?

Comment: @a2441918, now it collects all properties and take them as pattern with empty strings which are replaced by known values.

Answer (score 1):

Concat the arrays, group them by `id` or `rowId`, merge all objects and map the values to empty strings, map the object of groups, and merge each group with the defaults to an object (including default empty `id` and `name`).

```js
const { concat, groupBy, mapValues, map, merge } = _

const fn = (getId, ...arrs) => {
  const items = concat(...arrs);
  const defaults = mapValues(merge({}, ...items), () => '');

  return map(
    groupBy(items, getId),
    group => merge({}, defaults, ...group)
  )
}

const data1 = [{"name":"A","id":1},{"name":"B","id":2}]

const data2 = [{"city":"X","rowID":1},{"city":"Y","rowID":2},{"city":"Z","rowID":3}]

const result = fn(o => o.id ?? o.rowID, data1, data2)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What about name and id in the last object? Is there a way we can render them as empty string and I am sending this data to a table and it expects those values to be present. I am also okay to keep them as "-"

Comment: See we merge everything to an empty object, you can easily add defaults.

Comment: Keys are dynamic and will change per API. I am planning to use this as a reusable function where I pass in the two data, and their corresponding keys to match. Thanks